# C# ActiveUp Mail Cant fetch messages

Tags: c#, imap, gmail-imap

I'm trying to loop all the messages in specific inbox like using `ActiveUp Mail C#`:

```
Mailbox box = imap.AllMailboxes[0];
Fetch fetch = box.Fetch;
int messagesLeft = box.MessageCount; // return 31
int msgIndex = 0;

List<Email> list = new List<Email>();
for (int x = 1; x <= box.MessageCount; x++)
{
    try
    {
        Message msg = fetch.MessageObject(x);
        list.Add(new Email()
        { 
            /// .....
        }); 
    }
    catch { }
}
```

I'm getting an error for all the messages (except 1)..

> Index and length must refer to a location within the string.

all of the messages (Except the 1 that working well) are from the same sender and has the same format (different content)

Answer (score 0):

```
Imap4Client client = new Imap4Client();
client.Connect("server", 143);
client.Login("***", "***");
foreach (var box in client.AllMailboxes.OfType<Mailbox>())
{
  for (int i = 1; i <= box.MessageCount; i++)
  {
     // a u wish
     Header heade = box.Fetch.MessageObject(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you mean?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow but before you ask some question you should read the rule in stackoverflow. Please ask a clear question.